# How can I let the thymeleaf in springboot selectively process parts of my files?

Tags: thymeleaf

Say, I have two files, A.html and B.js. And I want A.html to be processed by template engine while B.js not to.

In default, when you implement thymeleaf and write codes like this:

```
@GetMapping("/B.js")
public String test(){
    return "B.js"
}
```

The B.js will be processed by thymeleaf. But actually, I don't need thymeleaf to do anything in this situation.

How can I return a file in its primitive state while I return other files through thymeleaf?

Comment: By simply using the <script> tag without Thymeleaf attributes. It is important that the header `Content-Type: text/javascript` is set in the response.